# Initialize a static member ( an array) in C++

Tags: c++

I intended to create a class which only have static members and static functions. One of the member variable is an array. Would it be possible to initialize it without using constructors? I am having lots of linking errors right now...

```
class A
{
public:
  static char a[128];
  static void do_something();
};
```

How would you initialize a[128]? Why can't I initialize a[128] by directly specifying its value like in C?

```
a[128] = {1,2,3,...};
```

Comment: There are several questions that go into initializing static class members.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493045/how-to-initialize-a-static-member

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can, just do this in your .cpp file:

```
char A::a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Comment: is there a static initializer available?

Comment: Yes.  In your .cpp file: `char A::a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}`

Answer (score 17):

If your member isn't going to change after it's initialized, C++11 lets you keep it all in the class definition with `constexpr`:

```
class A
{
public:
  static constexpr const char a[] = {1,2,3}; // = "Hello, World"; would also work
  static void do_something();
};
```

Comment: In C++14, `constexpr const char a[];` is still needed after the class declaration. In C++17, it is not needed.

Answer (score 12):

Just wondering, why do you need to initialize it inside a constructor?

Commonly, you make data member static so you don't need to create an instance to be able to access that member. Constructors are only called when you create an instance.

Non-const static members are initialized outside the class declaration (in the implementation file) as in the following:

```
class Member
{
public:
    Member( int i ) { }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    static int i;
    static char c[ 10 ];
    static char d[ 10 ];
    static Member m_;
};


int MyClass::i = 5;
char MyClass::c[] = "abcde";
char MyClass::d[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '\0' };
Member MyClass::m_( 5 );
```

Comment: would it be possible to have a static initializer in C++?

Comment: Is it acceptable to leave the size of the array undefined in the declaration within the class, and just let it autosize? Ex: `static char c[];` instead of `static char c[10];`?

Answer (score 0):

With `C+++17` and up, you can initialize it inline, as follows

```
class A
{
public:
  inline static char a[2]={1,1};
  static void do_something();
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, I have found out a different way to initialize without resorting to create additional items in the already spaghetti C++

```
char fred::c[4] = {};
```

Comment: There is nothing different about this solution from the accepted answer posted 7 years previously. What you may mean by 'create additional items' is a mystery.