# What is the proper syntax for initializing an array of hashtables in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, hashtable

How would I implement an Array of Hashtables in c++?

I have a hashtable class with a constructor that looks like this:

```
explicit ChainingHashTable( const HashedObj & notFound, int size = 101 );
```

So I attempted making an array of these hashtables by doing:

```
static ChainingHashTable<int> answers[5] = { {0, 500}, {0, 500}, {0, 500}, {0, 500}, {0, 500} };
```

however, I get the following errors & warnings:

```
browser.cpp:106:71: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
browser.cpp:106:71: error: converting to ‘ChainingHashTable<int>’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘ChainingHashTable<HashedObj>::ChainingHashTable(const HashedObj&, int) [with HashedObj = int]’
```

I can't use a different compiler since this is for a class assignment, but what am I doing incorrectly? What's the proper syntax?

Comment: It is being created in a class/object, so additionally, how would I initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize a static member ( an array) in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570235/initialize-a-static-member-an-array-in-c)

Comment: The simplest solution is avoiding the problem: do not use arrays, but rather vectors.

Comment: @David: That doesn't help with initialization pre-C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
static ChainingHashTable<int> answers[5] = { ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500) };
```

?

---

Above is the method for a global variable.  For a static class member, the declaration and definition must be separate:

```
class SomeClass
{
    static ChainingHashTable<int> answers[5];
};
```

and in one compilation unit (so not inside a header)

```
ChainingHashTable<int> SomeClass::answers[5] = { ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500), ChainingHashTable<int>(0, 500) };
```

Comment: I tried inserting that just now, but I get a whole new error:

Comment: browser.h:33:38: error: a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
In file included from browser.cpp:3:0:
browser.h:33:199: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘answers’ [-fpermissive]
browser.h:33:199: error: making ‘answers’ static [-fpermissive]
browser.h:33:199: error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type ‘ChainingHashTable<int> [5]’

Comment: @kabirpong: Oh, now I see that this is a member variable.  You didn't say that anywhere in the question and it's very important!

Comment: My bad guys! I realized it had to be a member variable after I posted the question.

Comment: I tried what was done in the other answer you posted, but I'm confused about one detail: How would I write the declaration? the compiler keeps comlpaining about the lack of a constructor

Comment: Okay, just saw your addition, seems like it worked so far, i'll have to double check in runtime. THanks a lot ben!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that the code you are trying to write is C++11.

You could use [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)

Comment: And his instructor is going to test with a compiler that doesn't support C++11, so how does this "answer" help?